# Connecting to MS sql through hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, hibernate, orm

I want to connect to MS SQl server 2005 using hibernate in java. i am unable to find the jars and the hibernate.cfg.xml file for the same. can someone help me with the same

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497725/connecting-to-ms-sql-through-hibernate/2497749#2497749), use any one driver. In case of  JTDS, use the following configuration.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://XX.XX.XXX.XX:YYYY/DB-NAME</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
. 
.
.
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And in case of Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver,

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://XX.XX.XXX.XX:YYYY/DB-NAME</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
. 
.
.
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Doesn't mention the name of file to save the above code into.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is the driver class and proper dialect.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378749.aspx

If you have the driver, then (at a minimum) you need to specify the connection properties:  http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/firstexample.shtml

The proper dialect appears to be:  `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect`

Answer (score 2):

> I am unable to find the jars.

Get a JDBC driver for SQL Server 2005 from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C47053EB-3B64-4794-950D-81E1EC91C1BA&displaylang=en) or use the open source alternative [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

> and the hibernate.cfg.xml file for the same

The dialect for SQL Server 2005 is `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect`.

The other params (like the driver class name, the jdbc URL) will depend on the driver you choose. Refer to the respective documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced and after lot of tries i found solution and its working fine for me

You can create connection using JNDI connection string also.

**In ApplicationContext.xml or applicationContext-resources.xml**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" lookup-on-startup="true" resource-ref="true"  jndi-name="jdbc/resourcename"/>
```

**In Apache Context.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/resourcename" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username=username password=password driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname />
```

**Add hibernate dialect in persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
```

Now just build your code and run on Apache server.