# Window 2008 Tomcat 7 MS SQL Server 2008R2 - JNDI JDBC Driver not recognized

Tags: windows, tomcat, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, jndi

First of all I must say that I've already looked for this problem and I've found several answers, none worked for me.

I have Tomcat 7 running as a service on Windows 2008 x64 with JDK 1.7.0.10.

I'm trying to use a JDBC Connection Pool, that I've successfully run in Tomcat 6.0.36 (Not installed as a service) on Windows 7 x86. The configuration was simple:

1. Copy sqljdbc4.jar into %CATALINA_HOME%\lib directory.
2. Edit %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\APP_NAME\META-INF\context.xml:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/APP_NAME">
       <Resource name="jdbc/poolConexiones"
               auth="Container"
               driverclassname="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
               maxactive="100"
               maxidle="30"
               maxwait="10000"
               username="user"
               password="pass"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Name">
       </Resource>
   </Context>
   ```
3. Edit web.xml:

   ```xml
   <resource-ref>
       <res-ref-name>jdbc/poolConexiones</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
       <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
   </resource-ref>
   ```

And it works fine!

However, when I tried to run the same application in

- a) w2008 x64 and tomcat (v 6 and 7) installed as service
- b) wXP x86 and tomcat (v 6 and 7) installed as service

following the same steps, I get:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

Then I tried different things:

- Modify jvm's classpath on service laucher:

  Java Classpath: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar

Works on WinXP, but it didn't work on w2008.

- Use regular Tomcat version (not service), modify Catalina.bat in order to include sqljdbc4.jar in classpath:

  if "%CLASSPATH%" == "" goto emptyClasspath
  set "CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;%CLASSPATH%;"
  :emptyClasspath
  set "CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;%CLASSPATH%%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar"

  if not "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" == "" goto gotTmpdir
  set "CATALINA_TMPDIR=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp"
  :gotTmpdir

Works on WinXP, but it didn't work on w2008

So, after repeating several times the same steps in different order and trying different versions of tomcat an Java, I don't know what else to do.

Please, remember that this application is running with this configuration in w7 x86 and tomcat 6 through NetBeans 6.91 without any modification, and it runs on Win XP x86 editing the classpath.

What's the problem then?

Comment: I made it work uninstalling tomcat 7, downloading ZIP version, unzipping it in a different folder (avoiding Program files), creating a launcher.bat (wich sets CLASS_PATH pointing to "...\sqljdbc4.jar") and, after repeating libraries configuration... IT WORKED!

Comment: Please refer below link, it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497725/connecting-to-ms-sql-through-hibernate/41045022#41045022

Comment: As far as I can tell, this problem is one of the case-sensitivity of XML configuration. It should have been `driverClassName` (and `maxActive`, `maxIdle` and `maxWait`). See also https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources

Answer (score 0):

On an additional note, if you have several instances of SQLServer running in your database service, you need to qualify the instance you are connecting to by providing the **instanceName** attribute in context.xml.  In Tomcat 6, context.xml is at CATALINA_HOME/conf folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/APP_NAME">
   <Resource name="jdbc/poolConexiones"
        auth="Container"
        driverclassname="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        maxactive="100"
        maxidle="30"
        maxwait="10000"
        username="user"
        password="pass"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=myInstance;databaseName=Name">
   </Resource>
</Context>
```