# JNDI Resource not available when using different ROOT Application in Tomcat 7

Tags: exception, tomcat, jndi, configuration-files, windows-server-2008-r2

I finally made work my App on tomcat, the problem was:

[Frist problem with JNDI JDBC resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318423/window-2008-tomcat-7-ms-sql-server-2008r2-jndi-jdbc-driver-not-recognized)

Now I have another problem:

I've changed default ROOT Application in Tomcat:

[%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml]

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
       <Context path="" docBase="MY_APP" reloadable="true" debug="0" cookies="false"></Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

Then, after restarting tomcat,  I tried to access: AND IT WORKED FINE!

Later I released a new version of MY_APP. I deployed it and I got the original problem AGAIN:
[Original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318423/window-2008-tomcat-7-ms-sql-server-2008r2-jndi-jdbc-driver-not-recognized)

I checked all the config files, everything seems to be ok, so I tried to access: `http://localhost/MY_APP` AND IT WORKED! But the problem accessing via  `http://localhost/` remains...

I've removed all the oher apps from "webapps" directory. Now webapps only contains MY_APP.
Accessing via

- `http://localhost/MY_APP` --> it works!
- `http://localhost/` --> JNDI JDBC Resource exception

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't found any explanation...

OS: Windows 2008 R2 Standart SP1
JVM: JDK 1.7u10
TOMCAT: apache-tomcat-7.0.34

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing double-deployment due to your inclusion of your `<Context>` element in `server.xml`.

First, stop doing that: remove the `<Context>` from `server.xml`.

Next, re-name your WAR file to `ROOT.war` (note that this is case-sensitive, even on filesystems that normally ignore case like NTFS) and put it into `%CATALINA_BASE%/webapps` (which is probably where it was, anyway).

Your webapp should contain a `META-INF/context.xml` file which is where your `<Context>` element should go, including any `<Resource>` elements as children. That's where you'll get your JNDI references set.

When properly deployed, your webapp should work as the default/ROOT context with JNDI working properly.