# Connecting to database using hibernate - connection url

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, sql-server-2014

I am trying to connect to a database using hibernate, I have read the documentation and user guild but I still cannot connect to the database.
The steps which I took:

1. adding all relevant hibernate jars and `sqljdbc41.jar` (sql server jdbc driver) to my project.
2. added an xml with the following `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (x64) to the environment path.
3. created a xml by the name `hibernate.cfg.xml` with the following connection and dialect:

   ```
       <!-- Database connection settings -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ForumSystem;integratedSecurity=true;"</property>

   <!-- SQL dialect -->
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
   ```

as you can see my server is local and I am using windows authentication, also I did not change the defualt instance and port.

I try to connection to the databse using the following code:

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection ["jdbc:sqlserver://SHPERB;databaseName=ForumSystem;integratedSecurity=true;"]
```

I have tried to modify the connection url to include the port and the instance name anyway and also tried to connect without windows authentication but made no progress.

Have I missed something? is there a way to know which of the parameters is wrong?

**Edit:** forgot to mention that TCP\IP is enabled in the SQL server configuration and that I allow both windows authentication and SQL authentication in the database.
If I try to connect using:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SHPERB;database=ForumSystem;integratedSecurity=true;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

it works, but not using hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver` in your url. Yoou need to specify driver for Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver. See more 
[Connecting to MS sql through hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497725/connecting-to-ms-sql-through-hibernate) and [how to configure hibernate config file for sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585544/how-to-configure-hibernate-config-file-for-sql-server)

Also check whether custom port is set and add it into the connection params.

Comment: Accordong to the documentation, there sould not be "microsoft:", I tested is just to make sure but it did not help.
And about the port, I took the connection string from the database which I already integreated to eclipse, and it uses the default port.